# Many to One in JPA creates nullable column for reference column

Tags: jpa

I have an employee table and employee reference table. Employee to Employee reference would be one to many relationship. An employee may have one or more employee reference rows.

```
employee reference table

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "pkey",name = "employee", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
Employee employee;

employee table

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "employee")
List<EmployeeReference> employeeReferenceList;
```

Please advise.

Comment: What is the primary key column name of the `employee` table?  Your code implies that it is `pkey`, but this information is not stored anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. The problem it has been saved as null is because the constraint is not properly build because of build issue. The above works fine. We can close this.

Comment: OK...just for another comment, sometimes I have found that dropping all tables and then restarting the application can help.

Comment: Thank you. How to close this as i don't have enough reputation. Can you please kindly close this for me.

Comment: I only have the ability to close questions if they are duplicates of something else.  But, this is a typo/non reproducible question.  I have voted to close, and if 2 others also vote, it will get closed.